# Converting a single string of numbers to a list containing those numbers

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

```
'15 12 4 4' to ['15','12','4','4'] or even [15, 12, 4, 4]
```

I'm not sure how to approach this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try yourString.split(" ").

Comment: `list(map(int, s.split()))`